# initialize ng2-select angular2 with selected data

Tags: angular, typescript, components

I would like to initialize my select in he first init, I'm using ng2-select

[ng2-select exemple link](https://valor-software.com/ng2-select/)

Comment: An example of your code would be nice, along with an explanation of what you've tried..

Comment: Hello, you can find an exemple in the link.

Answer (score 1):

i don't know exactly what you want to show on init. But i think you want to initialize something that would appear when the init execute

Here is some explanation:

```
<ng-select [allowClear]="true" [items]="A List of objects" [active]="list with single object " [disabled]="my_disabled" (data)="selected($event)" [multiple]="true" placeholder="No Selection" (selected)="onSelection($event)" (removed)="onRemove($event)"> </ng-select>
```

> [items]="A List of object(s)". you need a list and dictionary (object) or multiple dictionary (objects). 
>   For Exmaple: 
>   [{'id': 1, 'text': 'some text'}]. Dictionary object should be in form of this with id and text other wise it won't recognize it.

Here is your part i think so.

> [active]="assigned_variable" you need to assign your value in like this way assigned_varibale = [{'id': 1, 'text': 'some text'}]

so when you declare that variable in "init" it will shows the active selection when component starts.

For disabling the ng-select

> [disabled]="my_disabled" you can set to my_disabled variable as bool value. True or Either False for disable and enable ng-select

For Adding the multiple values

> (data)="selected($event)" This function (data) will allow you add multiple values to your function "selected($event)"

For multiple selection on ng-select

> [multiple]="true" .If you not want to select multiple values just remove that option. it will then give you single value selection

For selection event trigger and removing.

> (selected)="onSelection($event)" trigger the event for each time selection
>   (removed)="onRemove($event)" trigger the event for each time selection
>   removed